# Adding ios frameworks (like Google Maps API) to subversion won't allow working checkout

Tags: ios, xcode, svn, frameworks, google-maps-sdk-ios

I added the new Google Maps API framework to a project and checked it into subversion. The framework has the usual Apple structure which includes alias files that point to the actual static library and includes. Apparently XCode these days allows the use of the standard framework structure so you don't have to put header or library references in any more, merely adding the framework is sufficient.

However it appears that storing these in subversion does not work as the alias files seem to break when you check them out.

Anyone have an idea how to make this work? Clearly I can add manual references to the includes directory and the static library in the framework, ie the old fashioned way. It would be nice for this to just work somehow since people are shipping SDKs as proper frameworks now (Google, Crashlytics).

Update: The symbolic links inside the frame work are supposed to be stored in SVN marked as svn:special. However what I get back from checking this framework out is a symlink to the library, but with actual folders for Headers and Resources instead. This of course no longer  matches the SVN repository. I wonder if my svn client (Versions) might be messing it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone's client was messing up the checkin. Versions OSX seems to do it correctly but once it's checked in wrong, strange things start to happen. The solution is to remove it from the repository and check it in with the command line or a client that works correctly like Versions.

Answer (score 1):

I avoided putting symbolic links into SVN by copying the real GoogleMaps file and the real Headers and Resources folders from GoogleMaps.framework/Versions/A/ up into the GoogleMaps.framework folder, overwriting the symbolic links (and then I removed the Versions folder).

This is probably not the 'right' way to do it, but it seems to be working okay so far :)

Answer (score 0):

Update SVN global ignores:

Open terminal and execute:

```
vi ~/.subversion/config
```

Then search for global-ignores, and uncomment same line (remove # in first char). Then remove .a in same line

[image]

Comment: How does this fix the issue? Are there any side effects?

Comment: I use mountain lion os and subverion clienr svnX. So to upload lib file this change is must